# Nginx aliases and proxy_pass

Tags: web-hosting, nginx, configuration

I'm using nginx as web front-end and apache2 as web back-end. Apache runs several websites locally and nginx access them.

At the moment, different sub-domains are hosted, but I want to migrate them into a single one using `http://my-single-domain.com/subdomain-alias` thanks to nginx.

The root directory and the apache2 vhost port is different for each sub-domain (sounds obvious, doesn't it?).

I tried several configurations but I cannot get the resource being sent, i.e., the index html is sent but the resources are not found by the server (`404 Not Found`) despite the rule `root` being set.

I tried several solution such as:

```
location /alias1 {
  proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:9095/;
  include      /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
}
```

or

```
location /alias1 {
  alias  /alias1/;
  proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:9095/;
  include      /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
}
```

or even

```
location /alias1/ {
  rewrite ^/alias1(/.*)$ $1 break;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9095/;
}
```

or again

```
location /alias1/ {
  rewrite ^/alias1(/.*)$ $1 break;
  proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1:9095/;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

What is wrong with this setup?

Comment: This question is about server configuration and off topic here. It should be asked on serverfault.stackoverflow.com

Comment: And so it was, https://serverfault.com/q/761585/385320